# Use google analytics api under android

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I follow the tasks example http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html to create my Android app and when I execute a query with the google analytics API I always receive

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

but with the tasks demo it's working.